# Single Podspec for source and binary distribution using cocoapods

Tags: podspec

We are building an iOS SDK (using Objective-C). The SDK project is in cocoapod project structure (pod lib create). Now the requirement is to be able to distribute the SDK both as Source and Binary (Closed source).

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to use only a single podspec file for distributing both Source and Binary version of SDK. Moreover, there may exists multiple flavours of binary from the same codebase (i.e. Dynamic Framework, Static Framework, Dynamic Framework with Bitcode Enabled, Static Framework with Bitcode Enabled). For all of these flavours, I don't want to keep adding new podspec files.

Is there any customisation possible in podspec file to ensure single podspec file is used for different deliverables?

One solution is to zip all different binaries into a single zip and distribute it. But still two podspec is required for source and binary. I just want to use single podspec file.

I tried the option described in following post.

http://markspanbroek.github.io/2016/04/14/binary-cocoapods.html

But I am getting an error that "source" attribute cannot be used within subspec. Seems that it was an intermediate bug in cocoapods that allowed the above approach which doesn't work any more. I am using cocoapods version 1.5.3.

Comment: Do you need to use .zip and a "basic" URL? Because if you don't, you should be able to use a single source (git repo), and with the subspec add only the .framework needed for each subpsec.